# php quiz displaying number of correct and number of wrong answers

Tags: php, if-statement, counter

I have a php page with multiple choice quiz questions like this

```
<p>1. Is Manhattan near New York?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" value="3">
    Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" value="2">
    Maybe<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" value="1">
    No</p>
  <p>2. Do you like Indian food?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" value="1">
    Some times<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" value="3">
    Never<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" value="2">
    Always</p>
```

The page posts to itself and checks if the answer is right or wrong like this

```
if($ans1 == "3") { 
$test_complete .="Question one is <span class='green'>correct</span>, well done!<br/>";  
}else{ 
$test_complete .="Question one is <span class='red'>incorrect</span>!<br/>"; 
} 
// change the quest2 to the right answer
if($ans2 == "2") { 
$test_complete .="Question two is <span class='green'>correct</span>, well done!<br/>"; 
}else{ 
$test_complete .="Question two is <span class='red'>incorrect</span>!<br/>"; 
}
```

Now instead of telling the user that answer one or two is correct i would like to run a counter where it calculates the number of correct and number of wrong answers and displays it in two table boxes along with one box for total number of questions.

Comment: "Do you like Indian food?" "Never" "Your answer is incorrect!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. I would have an array of correct questions which corresponds the questions and then compare them. For example:

```
$correct_answers = array('3', '2');
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_questions; $i++)
{
   $ans_var = 'ans'.$i;
   if ($_POST[$ans_var] == $correct_answers[$i])
   {
      $score++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this...?

```
$result = $ans1 == 3;
$result += $ans2 == 2;
$result += $ans3 == 1;

echo "You got $result/3 questions right";
```

http://codepad.org/6zBQXQIT

Comment: @ABI, unless you are dynamically adding questions, then you should just be able to count them...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly...

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['total'])){$_SESSION['total']=0;}
if (!isset($_SESSION['correct'])){$_SESSION['correct']=0;}
if($ans1 == "3") {$_SESSION['correct']+=1;}
if($ans2 == "2") {$_SESSION['correct']+=1;}
if (isset($ans1) || isset($ans2)) {$_SESSION['total']+=1}
echo '<table><tr><td>Correct answers:</td><td>'.$_SESSION['correct'].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Wrong answers:</td><td>'.$_SESSION['total']-$_SESSION['correct'].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Total answers</td><td>'.$_SESSION['total'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: Why are you storing it in a session?

Comment: I thought there will be some posts for several questions, but not I understand, I probably got the question wrong.